# Having a challenge with a load, extract, transform and output console app using (C-sharp) - could do with some assistance

Tags: c#, file, console

I have the following in a large text file (contents.txt): with the following structure:

```
<attribute name="first_name" />
<attribute name="address" />
<attribute name="email" />
<attribute name="telephone" />
<attribute name="account_number" />
```

How do I read the text file, then extract the contents of everything inside: name="**first_name**" fields, one by one and output it into another file called "list.txt".

The problem I am having is that the contents.txt contains a list of other random text in there that are formatted as:

name="Marcus Aurelio was an emperor".

I am thinking that I need to take the full line:

```
<attribute name="first_name" />
```

when it matches that, extract the name and the output to a new file.

The output file, I am trying to format as follows:

```
item = first_name;
item = address;
item = email;
item = telephone;
item = account_number;
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there an XML type header in th is file, or just lines of attribute commands?

Comment: Just lines of attributes including some notes. It's a fairly fragmented file, but the only thing that is consistent is the attribute name. If I isolate this maybe I can output the contents the way I described.

Comment: So data looks like '<attribute name="spot the dog" />' ?

Comment: That's correct; I have a huge list of attributes, 300 or so. At the end of the file, there is just some notes by the creator.

Comment: So theres no indicator of  if its email, name, account number, phone number or even a record delimiter?

Comment: That's not really needed in this case. I just need to extract the data out of the attribute name, and then list then in another file with the output that I described:

Comment: Ok, but how can you tell  the lines apart? If its just name = value

Comment: Yes, they are all listed as described above. Each one on a separate line.

Comment: I must be thick. Can you show me some real data, or at least pseudo real data?

Comment: I don't think I am being very clear. I have a text file with a long list of attributes. I am only trying to extract the attribute name and put it in another file.

Comment: Ah so it doesnt look like my spot the dog example. It would be more like ' <attribute name="nickname" />spot the dog'

Comment: In your example; I don't really need anything else other than nickname. I don't want actual data, just the metadata. What I have to do is extract all the attributes from a big list, place it in a new file described as "item = nickname". I have to give that to a developer who uses the attribute name to write code. I hope that make sense because I think I'm stupid at explaining things.

Comment: Oh.  Maybe maybe not.  But it seems clearer. You could regexpression it and get matches. That would be fairly efficient. Although knowing you need to ignore the first x characters of the line, it maybe quicker to manipulate a line by hand..

Comment: What code do you have right now so far?

Comment: I just started; I'm trying many things out but fairly new to C#. http://pastebin.com/T4yETqKL